# How to use vue-speedometer library in nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-speedometer library in a nuxt app? I get the following error

[image]

Comment: It mentions it in the repo https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-speedometer#faq

Comment: Hi Lawrence I tried that but I still get the same error.  Is there a specific way to add it in the nuxt config file since this is a nuxt application is not a plain vue application

Comment: `// nuxt.config.js
{
  build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.resolve.alias["vue"] = "vue/dist/vue.common";` various places https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1142 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-runtime-template#getting-started